# Sequelize Join table1 with table[X] referenced in table1.column

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

So I have:

- table1=vehicles
- table2=cars
- table3=motocycle
- table4=trucks...

In table1, I have a column `type` which references by number one of the above tables (table2 | table3 | table4...). I would like to list all vehicles in table1 and join the table referenced in `type`; but I find that to be a bit hard the only way I find is to get all vehicles and loop through all and for each get the complementary data from the appropriate table specified in `type`.

For example:

**vehicles:**

```
id(0)------------type(1)---------------name(dacia)

id(1)------------type(2)---------------name(porsche)

id(2)------------type(2)---------------name(hummer)

id(3)------------type(3)---------------name(kongo)

id(4)------------type(3)---------------name(renault)
```

**cars(type 1):**

```
id(0)----------vehicleId(0)-------otherInfo(new)
```

**trucks(type 2):**

```
id(0)----------vehicleId(1)-------otherInfo(used)

id(1)----------vehicleId(2)-------otherInfo(like_new)
```

**motocycle(type 3):**

```
id(0)----------vehicleId(3)-------otherInfo(old)

id(1)----------vehicleId(4)-------otherInfo(very_old)
```

**Query Result:**

```
id(0)------------type(1)---------------name(dacia)-------otherInfo(new)

id(1)------------type(2)---------------name(porsche)-------otherInfo(used)

id(2)------------type(2)---------------name(hummer)-------otherInfo(like_new)

id(3)------------type(3)---------------name(kongo)-------otherInfo(old)

id(4)------------type(3)---------------name(renault)-------otherInfo(very_old)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LEFT JOIN clauses that include a condition on the vehicule type, and then use CONCAT/COALESCE to return the (only) matching value, like so :

```
select
    v.id,
    v.type,
    v.name,
    concat( 
        coalesce( c.otherInfo, ''), 
        coalesce( t.otherInfo, ''), 
        coalesce( m.otherInfo, '') 
    ) as otherInfo
from vehicules v
left join cars      c on c.vehiculeId = v.id and v.type = 1
left join trucks    t on t.vehiculeId = v.id and v.type = 2
left join motocycle m on m.vehiculeId = v.id and v.type = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read this first : **[Associations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html)**

This is how you can define the relations b/w two models/tables , like

> - BelongsTo
> - Belongs-To-Many
> - HasOne
> - hasMany

Once you are done with this, then you can query the model to get realted data as you are expecting. example

```
// Find all projects with a least one task where task.state === project.state
Project.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Task
        // you can go nested too , as per your requirment        
    }]
})
```

> **This is how you should be doing when you are using the sequelize.js**

Comment: yes indeed, that's what i do, the only problem here is that the model that i should include depends on the value of **`type`**